# Get 2 GridPanes in one Class in 2 Different Scenes

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I want to create a separate scene using the gridpane layout. I have tried basically copying all the code and creating a new scene, but everything i put in the 2nd scene doesn't snap to the grid. I'm fairly **new** to coding, and this is my 5th project. (so sorry for the bad code)

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    Stage window;
    Scene s1, s2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("Test");

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setHgap(10);

        Button b1 = new Button("Scene 2");
        b1.setOnAction(e -> window.setScene(s2));
        GridPane.setConstraints(b1, 2, 0);

        Button b2 = new Button("Button 2");
        GridPane.setConstraints(b2, 5, 0);

        grid.getChildren().addAll(b1, b2);
        Scene s1 = new Scene(grid, 500, 500);

        GridPane grid2 = new GridPane();
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setHgap(10);

        Button b3 = new Button("Scene 1");
        b3.setOnAction(e -> window.setScene(s1));
        GridPane.setConstraints(b3, 0, 0);

        Button b4 = new Button("Button 2");
        GridPane.setConstraints(b4, 6, 0);

        grid2.getChildren().addAll(b3, b4);
        s2 = new Scene(grid2, 500, 500);


        window.setScene(s1);
        window.show();
    }


}
```

Comment: You just have an obvious copy-and-paste error: you didn't set the padding, hgap, or vgap on `grid2`.

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesn't snap to the grid' ? I've run your code and it works fine, except that in scene 2, it doesn't show proper spacing. That's because, as James said, you didn't set the vgap and hgap for grid2.

Comment: Thank you so much @James_D I didn't realize that the grid.setPadding etc. had to be labeled grid2. I just thought it was generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a copy-and-paste error in the code.

```
    GridPane grid2 = new GridPane();
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
    grid.setVgap(10);
    grid.setHgap(10);
```

presumably came from copying the code above, where the padding and gaps were applied to the first grid pane. To apply them to the second grid pane, it should be

```
    GridPane grid2 = new GridPane();
    grid2.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
    grid2.setVgap(10);
    grid2.setHgap(10);
```